# SELECT deve mostrar a data mais antiga para todos os registro do mesmo atendimento

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, oracle, select

Estou fazendo um relatório da passagem de pacientes pelos leitos do hospital.

Então o mesmo atendimento (da tabela atendimento) pode ter várias internações (na tabela internação), e cada internação tem seu horário.

Preciso trazer o horário da primeira internação, para todas as internações seguintes

No banco as informações ficam assim:

| ID_Atendimento | ID_Internação | Data | Hora |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 752 | 15/04/2021 | 22:10:47 |
| 3 | 810 | 16/04/2021 | 13:40:22 |
| 3 | 904 | 16/04/2021 | 23:05:56 |

Com mais filtros, a primeira internação não seria resgatada pelo SELECT, porem, o horário da primeira internação deve ser o mesmo nas internações seguintes, ficando assim:

| ID_Atendimento | ID_Internação | Data | Hora |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 810 | 15/04/2021 | 22:10:47 |
| 3 | 904 | 15/04/2021 | 22:10:47 |

```
SELECT  
       ATE.ID_ATENDIMENTO,
       M.ID_INTERNACAO,
       
       TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(M.DT_MOV_INT,'DD/MM/RRRR'),'DD/MM/RRRR') || ' ' || TO_CHAR(M.HR_MOV_INT,'HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS')  "INTERNOU EM:",
FROM mov_int m, atendimento ate 
WHERE ATE.ID_ATENDIMENTO = M.ID_ATENDIMENTO,
```

Ja usei min, mas não dá certo, pois ele pega a data do primeiro registro no banco de dados

```
MIN(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(M.DT_MOV_INT,'DD/MM/RRRR'),'DD/MM/RRRR') || ' ' || TO_CHAR(M.HR_MOV_INT,'HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS'))
```

Comment: "Já usei min, mas não dá certo". Parece-me que você colocou ele no local errado, teria que ser em `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(MIN(M.DT_MOV_INT),'DD/MM...`.

Comment: Qual o type de DT_MOV_INT ? em geral (sendo DATE) um sub como .... select * from tabela t1 where t.data = (select min(t2.data) from tabela t2 where t2.chave = t1.chave)  ... funciona

Comment: @Benilson o min dentro não deu certo também.

Comment: @Motta ficou assim:
select *
from mov_int t1 
where t1.DT_MOV_INT = (select min(t2.DT_MOV_INT) from mov_int t2 where t1.cd_atendimento = t2.cd_atendimento and t2.cd_atendimento = 377783)

Esse Select retorna a linha de menor data, não retornado as outras linhas mais recentes.

Comment: @Leo B , não era o que você queria ?

Comment: @Motta , é 50% do que eu preciso
Quando o paciente interna gera 1 registro
Havendo troca de leito gera um segundo registro

Preciso que a data e hora do segundo registro seja a data do primeiro.

(Quando eu fizer um Select o primeiro registro pode não entrar no resultado por exemplo, quero ver quem estava no hospital no mês de Fev, o paciente pode ter entrado em 30/01 em um leito e no dia seguinte 31/1 foi transferido e teve alta no dia 02/02.
O primeiro registro 30/1 - 31/1, não vai aparecer nesse resultado, mas o segundo sim, 31/1 - 2/2. Porém, tem q mostrar a data e hora do primeiro

Comment: Tente fazer o MIN em um subselect como tabela virtual e o join nesta tabela , o que complica é que seu campo de data e hora não parecem ser "date" o que complica o "min"

Comment: Voltei um mês depois, havia deixado esse relatório de lado para focar em outros e voltei agora. Ficou assim 
SELECT DISTINCT
       a.cd_atendimento Atendimento,
       (select min(xx.Dt_Mov_Int) from mov_int xx where xx.cd_atendimento = a.cd_atendimento) datatest
FROM mov_int A